# Unable to upgrade virtualenv with Python3.5 and Python2.7 on the same machine

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-3.5

Python 2.7 is the default version on my RHEL box. I also have Python 3.5 installed and added the following to my .bachrc file:

```
alias python=/usr/bin/python3.5
```

I run `python -V` and it indicates 3.5. All good.

I then run:

```
 pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

I get the following error:

```
No distributions at all found for virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I'm wondering why 2.7 is still be referenced?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the contents of `pip` you will notice that it's just a Python script, and it has a shebang line (`#!`) pointing to your old python. Try this

```
cat $(which pip)
```

You probably have a `pip3.5` program, and you can alias it like this

```
alias pip=/usr/bin/pip3.5
```

Otherwise you can always run pip like this

```
python3.5 -m pip install <package>
```